# Check if value from website table already exists in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a table on the web page. Items are loaded while scrolling the list. It also works so, that it is loading and unloading items. So there is no way to scroll it all the way down first and then load items. Also, log in to a web page is required in order to see the table so Selenium seems to be the only option. After proceeding to the correct web page with a table, there are already some items, but in order to get them, all the tables should be scrolled down step by step.

I was working on a method that will:

1. Load what is visible to List
2. Compare what is visible to what we already have in the table
3. If not found in List, scroll down
4. Add new items to list

My current code is able to load visible items after page load:

```
public class UserTableRow
{
    private readonly IWebElement row;

    public string Username => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text;
    public string Firstname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l1 r1')]")).Text;
    public string Lastname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l2 r2')]")).Text;
    public string Type => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l3 r3')]")).Text;
    public string Crew => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l4 r4')]")).Text;
    public string JobTitle => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l5 r5')]")).Text;
    public string DefaultPrice => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l6 r6')]")).Text;
    public string Future => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l7 r7')]")).Text;
    public string Language => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l8 r8')]")).Text;

    //public override string ToString()
    //{
    //    return "TableRow: " + Username.ToString() + ": " + Firstname.ToString();
    //}

    public UserTableRow(IWebElement row)
    {
        this.row = row;
    }
```

Here is the method itself. For some reason, it is failing at checking `bool AlreadyExist = DataHere.Any(cus => cus.Username == row.Text);` - if item already exists in IEnumerable as nothing is scrolled down. Any ideas on how it can be fixed?

```
    public static IEnumerable<UserTableRow> AddItemsToList(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        var rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"));

        // This part will get our first visible items in table to list, after page load 
        var DataHere = from row in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"))
                       select new UserTableRow(row);

        // We need to select table first to be able to scroll down. We do it directly here
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]/div[5]/div/div[14]/div[1]")).Click();

        // Now we will iterate through cells in the table and compare to what we already have in the list
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            // Define variable for comparison
            bool AlreadyExist = DataHere.Any(cus => cus.Username == row.Text);

            // If item already exist, scroll down and add to list
            if (AlreadyExist == true)
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("{PGDN}");
                DataHere.Add(new UserTableRow(row));

            }
        }

        return DataHere;
    }
```

Comment: Your row data might not be being built as expected in `UserTableRow`, when you do `row.FindElement(By.XPath...`  - it's not looking for a child element inside `row`. Even with the `.` The double backslash part means relative to the page - i've had fun figuring this out in the past.  if it's the wrong data, your linq is not going to validate the username ... can you confirm your `DataHere` object contains all the data you expect?  (and not just the first one over and over).... IF that is the case - solution is to change to use css selectors (not xpaths) in `UserTableRow`

Comment: Code looks good and question is good too - can you share a link to the page as i'd like to have a play? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what could be the exact reason why the comparison fails.
However, I can try to suggest several approaches to find the problem in your code.

First, lets apply `ToList()` at the end of your query for `DataHere` to skip possible multiple call for the `driver.FindElements(...)`:

```cs
var DataHere = (from row in 
                    driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row")) 
                    select new UserTableRow(row)).ToList();
```

Second, even before getting into `foreach` loop, it would be wise to check if your `DataHere` has items, otherwise, you will be guaranteed to have `false` results for every `AlreadyExist` check.

```cs
// Now we will iterate through cells in the table and compare to what we already have in the list
if (DataHere.Any())
{
   foreach (var row in rows)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

And the last point, ask yourself:

> What kind of check am I performing (exact or contain)?

If the answer is "contain" then use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1) or [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) method for comparing `cus.Username` and `row.Text`.

> Is the check case sensitive or not?

If the answer is not case sensitive then apply one of the [ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netcore-3.1), [ToLowerInvariant()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=netcore-3.1), [ToUpper()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netcore-3.1), [ToUperInvariant()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupperinvariant?view=netcore-3.1) methods to both `cus.Username` and `row.Text` during comparison.

Finally, if both of the above points are true then combine the suggestions.